# How to use late when referring to a specific point in the life of a relatively famous person who is recently deceased?

Tags: word-usage, expressions, adjectives, american-english, north-american-english

[Christopher Eckhardt](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tinker_v._Des_Moines_Independent_Community_School_District) was 16 years old when he took the actions I'm referring to. (Just for the record, the actions in question occurred in December of 1965). Mr. Eckhardt died at age 62 on December 27th, 2012.

The section here on usage of the word late (referring to death, not punctuality) suggests that it is appropriate for this context, but I can't figure out a way to use it in conjunction with his age at the time.

I know that the construction/sentence/mess that I have now is clearly wrong, but I have not the slightest clue how to fix it.

On that note, the monstrosity reads as follows:

"In December 1965, a group of students, meeting in the home of the ***late, then 16-year-old*** Christopher Eckhardt, of Des Moines, Iowa, made a plan to publicly display their support for a truce in the Vietnam war by wearing black armbands throughout the holiday season."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could put late before his name and location, and 16 years old after it.

> In December 1965, a group of students, meeting in the home of the late Christopher Eckhardt, of Des Moines, Iowa, then 16 years old, made a plan to publicly display their support for a truce in the Vietnam war by wearing black armbands throughout the holiday season."

Assuming his home was in Des Moines, you could also put that at the beginning of the sentence. With a little rejiggering, it reads like this:

> In December 1965, a group of students in Des Moines, Iowa, met in the home of the late Christopher Eckhardt, then 16 years old, and made a plan to publicly display their support for a truce in the Vietnam war by wearing black armbands throughout the holiday season."

Comment: I really like the second answer, and I think that I'll be using something like that in my final piece. Thanks very much for your thoughtful and prompt answer.